# Whole app freezes, when opening UISearchController in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm making an app with a list of crypto-currencies. There should be an ability to make a search within those 3 filtered lists (BTC, ETH, USD). The only problem i have is with the search bar.

[image: Before opening Search Bar]

[image: After opening Search Bar]

As soon as i press on the "magnifying glass" icon, the search bar presents, but the whole app freezes. I'm not able to press "Cancel", type in the bar, close it and move the UITableView. I don't understand the reason of such behavior.

```
var searchController : UISearchController!

@IBAction func searchingButton(_ sender: Any) {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "All currency pairs"
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    definesPresentationContext = true
    navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

    searchButton.isHidden = true

    present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


extension ViewController:  UISearchControllerDelegate {
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        navigationItem.searchController = nil
        navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
        navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.indexChange(self.segmentedControl!)
    }
}
```

Please help me with this problem. If needed, more code will be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's weird, but cleaning the project and system reboot helped.